# How to Arrange Items using React BootStrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to do this

But additional columns just go underneath the image. Here is what I'm trying

```
<Container>
                <Form >
                    
                <Col>
                    {hello}
                </Col>

                </Form>
            </Container>
            );
```

I thought that adding another Col would shift anything to the right but it just goes underneath the image. Without using padding or margin, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You Have to define a `<Row>` tag outside the `<Col>` tags

```
<Container>
    <Form className = "JobBox">
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Image
                    width={161}
                    height={106}
                    src= {require("./office.jpg")}
                    rounded/>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                {location}
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Form>
</Container>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this moves everything to the middle of the row but I need it right to the first image though

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bootstrap `col` have `block` for its `display` CSS property. This means it will automatically take up the entire `width` of its parent unless a `width` is defined. Take a look at its other properties as well:

> ```
> .col {
>     flex-basis: 0;
>     flex-grow: 1;
>     min-width: 0;
>     max-width: 100%;
> }
> ```

If you have multiple `col` in 1 row, it will basically eat up similar spaces due to `flex-grow: 1`. As a minimal fix to your layout, just wrap the content in a `row` and place all the "job" information on a separate `col`. Take note I have not wrapped the Image in a `col` because of the aforementioned properties. I suggest defining its `width` etc

```
<Container>
  <Form className="JobBox">
    <Row>
      <Image
        width={161}
        height={106}
        src={"https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"}
        rounded
      />
      <Col>
        <div>Some Text</div>
        <div>Another Text Text</div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Form>
</Container>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-mcnulty-0v2tb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Do you know how to make this mobile friendly because when testing this on a mobile device the length of the box requires me to scroll horizontally a lot

Comment: Yes, utilize `max-width` and relative length measurements such as `vw` & `%` to ensure your content does not go beyond the user's screen in terms of the x-axis. Horizontal scrolling in this type of layout is not a good user experience. Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) as necessary to help you with wrapping. hope this helps

Comment: I've tried using max width and implementing % however the result is the same. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: Yes, here are some examples of the BS Grid System: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid. "It’s built with flexbox and is fully responsive." -docs

Comment: Okay I've read the doc but no where in it mentions the vw or %, could you show me how it's done in the codesandbox?

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue. Fork my sandbox and type some long text, it will wrap if needed